# Start view not in 0 0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I create background layer. For example, it has width x height 900 x 900. And view start location is 0,0:

```
    background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"back2.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:background];
```

I also have function to move view to point. It's work. But if i add start view not in 0;0 it cut background or jump to 0,0.

How can i do start view in center of background?

Answer (score 1):

Hope the code below will help you. Also, I will strongly recommend you to learn and understand about [anchorPoint in cocos2d](http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/). It will be handy, I guarantee that.

```
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"back2.png"];
background.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
background.position = ccp(winSize.width * 0.5, winSize.height * 0.5);
[self addChild:background];
```

Answer (score 0):

how about set anchorPoint to ccp(0.5,0.5) and calculate your desired destination?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you....

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];

background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

[self addChild:background z:-1];
```